# Proving that $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

Prove that $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ is continuous at all $x \notin \Bbb N$.

An attempt:

We should consider showing that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ converges uniformly.

Also,

$$f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2n}\left(\frac{1}{n-x}+\frac{1}{n+x}\right)$$

Comment: For every $x \ne n$? $n$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$....

Comment: bad choice of words.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use the uniform convergence theorem.

Comment: I made a mistake: its converges uniformly and not absolutely.

Comment: I think you have to ban natural $x$....

Comment: Hmmm... I changed my mind. It doesn't really look like it converges uniformly at all. Choosing $x = k+\tfrac 1 2$ for increasing $k$ pushes off convergence as far as you like.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'm being silly.

Comment: ok, so its not converges uniformly. Therefor fixing $x$, we just need to show that the series converges, and it does, as behaves similarly to $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$. Right?

Comment: Just saw the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $k\in \mathbb Z$ and $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $a<b$ and $[a,b]\subset (k,k+1)$ then:
$$\frac{1}{|n^2-x^2|}\leq c_n=\max\left(\frac{1}{|n^2-a^2|},\frac{1}{|n^2-b^2|}\right)\quad\forall\ x\in [a,b]$$
and the series 
$$\sum_n c_n$$
is convergent since $c_n\sim_\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ so the given series is uniformly convergent in every interval $[a,b]$ and with the continuity of the functions $x\mapsto \frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ we can conclude.